# Correct use of REQUIRE_BASE_URL with django-require

Tags: javascript, django, requirejs

I am trying to get `django-require` working to manage JS dependencies and minification. However, I am having difficulty with the requireJS `baseUrl`.

`require.js` is at `project/static/require.js`, and page JS is at `project/static/pages/pageA.js` and so on.

The following are the django-require settings.

```
REQUIRE_BASE_URL = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
REQUIRE_BUILD_PROFILE = 'app.build.js'
REQUIRE_JS = "require.js"
REQUIRE_STANDALONE_MODULES = {}
REQUIRE_DEBUG = DEBUG
REQUIRE_EXCLUDE = ("build.txt",)
REQUIRE_ENVIRONMENT = "auto"
```

I can't get the base URL to be correct during static file collection/processing and when serving via the browser. If I set it like this:

```
REQUIRE_BASE_URL = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
```

then the compilation process is successful (`node` finds `r.js` and so on). However, the template tags like `{% require_module pages/pageA %}` render like this:

```
<script data-main="/var/www/project/static/pages/pageA.js" src="/var/www/project/static/require.js"></script>
```

This fails from the browser side, as the path is the path on the machines actual file system, not in the website structure!

However, if I set the base URL like this:

```
REQUIRE_BASE_URL = 'static'
```

then the compilation step fails, since `r.js` is being called with a path that doesn't exist on the local file system (but would exist on the web site):

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/require/storage.py", line 50, in run_optimizer
  raise OptimizationError("Error while running r.js optimizer.")
```

The rendered script tags are correct in this case.

What is the right way to feed `r.js` the local file paths, but output website-relevant paths in the template tag using `django-require`?

Edit: also posted to the django-require mailing list [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-require/kVUgulN4uf0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, RequireJS works a lot better if all main scripts (as would be set as data-main on the requirejs script tag), are in the root of the baseUrl.

So, in your case, I'd use all the default settings for django-require, and then just set REQUIRE_BUILD_PROFILE.

I'd then place all your data-main scripts in the root of your js folder.

The author of RequireJS actually recommends keeping the folder structure very simple for RequireJS projects.

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles

Comment: Reducing the settings in settings.py to only `REQUIRE_BUILD_PROFILE = "app.build.js"` (and `STATICFILES_STORAGE`) seems to have worked. I can still link up all the JS using relative paths without flattening the tree, so that wasn't breaking things. `collectstatic` optimisation works too, as well as standalone module building.